# Price Modifier Configurator field not affecting price

Tags: cartthrob

The price modifier configurator displays the options (and prices) correctly on the product page, but the cart displays the base price instead of adding the item_option:price.

I'm using the sample code from the CT documentation (http://cartthrob.com/docs/tags_detail/item_options/index.html) which doesn't include the {item_price} field but according to this: http://cartthrob.com/docs/tags_detail/cart_items_info/index.html I should be able to use {item_price:plus_tax} to show the item's price including options + tax, which only displays the item's base price + tax.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Same issue here